# "Format of predictions is invalid." error en R

Tags: r

Estoy intentando dibujar la curva ROC para los resultado de mi clasificador Naive Bayes.

```
attach(TrainFactor)

NB <- naiveBayes(Result~., data=TrainFactor)
NB_pred <- predict(NB, TestFactor, type = c("class"))
NB_table <- table(NB_pred, TestFactor[,31])

## ROC 
NB_predictiontest <- prediction(NB_pred,TestFactor$Result)
NB_perftest <- performance(NB_predictiontest,"tpr","fpr")

plot(NB_perftest,col="blue",lwd=2, main="Naive Bayes ROC Curve")
```

Pero me imprime un error cuando intento ejecutar la función "prediction":

```
Error in prediction(NB_pred, TestFactor[, 31]) : 
  Format of predictions is invalid.
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme con esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice [Matias](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/9328/matias-thayer), la curva ROC evalúa un vector de probabilidades. Se genera a partir de los resultados de la clasificación considerando distintos puntos de corte, entonces necesitas tener la predicción no como clase, sino como probabilidad. Por defecto, devuelve las probabilidades, así que no hace falta poner nada en `type`.

```
NB_pred <- predict(NB, TestFactor)
```

(Además deberías asegurarte que `TestFactor$Result` sea binario)

Answer (score 0):

El ROC es una métrica para evaluar un clasificador binario y evalúa un vector de probabilidades (entre 0 y 1) contra los valores reales de tu set de validación.

Prueba con algo como 
`NB_pred <- predict(NB, TestFactor, type = "probs")`
( No estoy seguro de la sintaxis)